# Is it possible to set more than one model into MVCForm?

Tags: forms, model, atk4

I have three database tables with foreign keys to each other, and I want to insert data into those tables. I created three models and MVCForm. How can I insert data into those three tables with one MVCForm?

Comment: @jancha have made that possible with 4.1 branch by creating a custom controller. It will be also supported in 4.2.

Comment: yeah, we created multi-controller.

Comment: Can you give an example how to use it?

Comment: @jancha perhaps you can add it to atk4-addons ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create regular fields in the MVCForm, since it's child of Form, so you should be able to do:

```
$f=$this->add('MVCForm');
$m=$f->setModel('M1');

$f->addField('field_model2');

if($f->isSubmitted()){

   $f->update();

   $id=$m->get('id');

   $m2=$this->add('Model_M2');
   $m2->set('field2',$f->get('field_model2'));
   $m2->update();
}
```